# Following a pattern when rendering items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

In my react app I'm rendering recipe names and their images, they're rendered inside a row but the thing is that they should be disturbed each item inside col-4 in the first row, then each item in col-3 in the second row, then the third one goes back to col-4, then the fourth row col-3, and so on, they're being rendered but how am i going to change the columns distribution inside the rows? here is the mapping:

```
 renderRecipes() {
    return this.state.recipes.map(recipe => (
     <div class="row">
     //col should be changed here, once col-4 and in the next col-3, and to keep the pattern going
      <div class="col-4"> 
        <img src={recipe.img}/>
        <h3>{recipe.name}</h3>
       </div>
     </div>
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you can add an `i` index to the map and see if we are on an odd or even row. If odd, then `i % 2` will remainder `1` and you can choose which class to add based on this boolean.

```
 renderRecipes() {
    return this.state.recipes.map((recipe,i) => (
     <div class="row">
     //col should be changed here, once col-4 and in the next col-3, and to keep the pattern going
      <div class="{i % 2 === 1 ? 'col-3':'col-4'}"> 
        <img src={recipe.img}/>
        <h3>{recipe.name}</h3>
       </div>
     </div>
    ));
  }
```

Edit
Bootstrap will wrap `col`s that exceed the row onto the next row. You can use this to print all the `col`s horizontally and they will wrap onto the correct rows. You just need to find some maths that will determine if you are in a 3 or a 4 span row.

```
 renderRecipes() {
    let isThree = function(i){
      //Here add algorithm to determine if you are in a 3 row or a 4 row.
    }

    return (
     <div class="row">
       this.state.recipes.map((recipe,i) => (

         <div class="{isThree(i) ? 'col-3':'col-4'}"> 
           <img src={recipe.img}/>
           <h3>{recipe.name}</h3>
         </div>

       ));
     </div>
    )


  }
```

Comment: your code puts one item in each row, the first row should have 3 items with col-4, and the second row should have 4 items each in col-3

Comment: Night time here, let me know if it's not solved tomorrow morning

Comment: can you help please?